# Insert row number into cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following simple Excel spreadhseet:

```
       A              B           C           D           E
1                   2019-01    2019-02     2019-03
2   Product A        50          40           30
3   Product B        80         100          120
4                   
5                   Product A
6
```

I defined the `Row 2:2` as variable name in the name manager:

```
First_Row = "2:2"
```

For the value in `Cell B5` I use the following VBA which inserts the first value it finds in `First_Row` which in this case is `Product A`:

```
Sub Row_Number()
Row = Sheet1.Range("First_Row")
Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = First_Row
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now instead of the first value in `First_Row` I want to insert the `2:2` as value in `Cell B5`. Therefore, I tried to go with the following:

```
Sub Row_Number()
    Row = Sheet1.Range(Range("First_Row").Value)
    Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = Row
End Sub
```

However, with this I get

> runtime error 1004.

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my code to make it work?

Comment: Did you mean `Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = Sheet1.Range("A2").Value `?

Comment: No, my desired result is cell B5 = "2:2"

Comment: Then `Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = "2:2"`

Comment: Yeah, that is bascially the result I want. However, instead of inserting it directly with Value ="2:2" I want to store it in a variable in VBA and then insert it.

Comment: Then `YourVariable = "2:2"` and use it `Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = YourVariable`

Comment: Yeah that is a way to do it in this case. However, in my original file I will use a name instead of the "2:2" so the "2:2" is not a fixed range. Therefore, I somehow need to get the variable as indirect value.

Comment: Well then show a **real** code example for this, and explain your issue better. You change your question everytime I answer: Try `Range("2:2").Address`

Comment: I will open a new question with a better explanation of it so you can answer it there. I will post a link here. Sorry, for the inconvenience. I just simplified things too much.

Comment: You can [edit] this question to improve it. You don't need to open a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Range.Address property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Row_Number()
    Dim RowAddress As String
    RowAddress = Sheet1.Range("First_Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
    Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = RowAddress 
End Sub
```

Note that you should use `Option Explicit` to make sure all your variables are declared properly.

---

The issue that if the address is `2:2` and Excel writes it to the cell as a time `02:02` can be solved by adding a `'` infront of the address. This will force Excel to handle it as text, the `'` is not shown in the cell.

```
RowAddress = "'" & Sheet1.Range("First_Row").Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to eliminate the 0 before the 2 when I insert it into B5?

Comment: @Michi there is no `0` before. Check your number format in B5 and make sure it is `General` or `Text`.

Comment: The weird thing is if I define it as "Standard" and then I run the VBA it changes its format from Standard to customized hh:mm.

Comment: @Michi Because `2:2` is recognized as a time value (Excel tries to think here and fails). Use a `'` right before your address like `RowAddress = "'" & …`

Answer (score -1):

try This macro
don't use Row as range,Because ***Row*** is a keyword text

The Best is to use Row_  or anything else

```
Option Explicit
Sub Row_Number()
Dim Row_ As Range
Set Row_ = Sheet1.Rows("2:2")
Sheet1.Range("B5").Value = Row_.Cells(1)
End Sub
```